# Reading XLSX using FlatFileReader

Tags: java

Hi iam trying to Read xlsx file using FlatFileReader with the help of XSSFWorkBook,but reading using XSSFWorkBook is fine but while trying to read the sheet using FlatFileReader we are unable to read.code looks like below please check out

```
String fileName = "E:\\LLS-6192013-42631.csv";
   File file = new File(fileName);
   FileSystemResource fsr = new FileSystemResource(fileName);


   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileName);
   int sheetIndex = 0;
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
   //System.out.println("sheet content : " + sheet); 



   ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
     "classpath:/launch-context.xml");

   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader = (FlatFileItemReader) appContext
     .getBean("redemptionReader");

   flatFileItemReader.setResource(resource);
```

How to read the xlsx file using FlatFileReader?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a XSLX with a flat file item reader, because it is not a flat file with items with simple delimiters between them. If you want to read a XSLX file, use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

But according to your code you are reading a CSV file. This can be done as a flat file, or easier with the [Apache Common CSV library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

So check the exact format of your file and use the according library :-)